# "Load features" or "Loading features"?

Tags: word-choice, american-english

Context: An application can load and save data. These operations have different features.

What sounds more natural in the US English to describe them - "Load features" or "Loading features" ("Save features" or "Saving features")? Maybe other variants?

Comment: Could they be called load/save options?

Comment: They can. But again, what's better-load options or loading options? 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Loading features**, since you want the verb "to load" to turn into an adjective that describes "features". Just like *cleaning supplies*, *eating utensils*.

*Load features* would make the noun "load" become the adjective, which has a different meaning.

Comment: Thanks! What's the meaning of the phrase when the noun "load" become the adjective?

Comment: Well the most common definition is this: the amount of weight carried, especially by a vehicle, a structure such as a bridge, or an animal https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/load

Answer (score 1):

For a description of an action that can be done (like in a button that does the action when pressed), "load features" is the better way. If it's a progress bar, "loading features" is better because the intent is to be "(the application is) loading features".

Comment: Yeah, it's a little bit confusing. I mean, it's a noun and an adjective.  "load features" means "the features of the load operation". I'm trying to find a better way how to name them. 